# I want to search whether username and password is presenty in my json or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have tried many ways of doing this but it is just not getting me what i am looking for.I have no idea about JSON,this is what I could understand from net.

```
var loginDataList = [{
    "username": "abc",
    "password": "abc123"
}, {
    "username": "richa",
    "password": "richa123"
}];

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(loginDataList);

if ((username in jsonString) && (password in jsonString))
    alert("woola");
else
    alert("nope");
```

I also tried:

```
if (jsonString.has("username"))
    $('h2').text('Woollaaaa ').delay(1000).hide(1);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? You hardcoded the string `"username"` in your `has()`  which is a bit confusing as to what you are actually trying to do

Comment: Note that broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation....see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

`if(jsonString.indexOf('username') && jsonString.indexOf('password'))` gives you -1 if it is not present, greater than -1 if present.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>

        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script>
        var loginDataList = [{"username":"abc","password":"abc123"}, {"username":"richa","password":"richa123"}];


        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(loginDataList);
        console.log(jsonString);
        if(jsonString.indexOf('username') && jsonString.indexOf('password')){
            alert("Present");
        }
        else{
            alert("Not");
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee they are the same user .... just that both those values exist somehwere

Comment: this will work for  loginDataList = [{"abc":"username","password":"abc123"}, {"username":"richa","password":"richa123"}]; as input too. where key is 'abc' and value is 'username'; i guess stringify does'nt help in that vase. hope we can use the loginDataList as object to loop over for keys

Comment: You can delimit them. `if (jsonstring.indexOf('"username":"richa"') !=-1)...`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var loginDataList = [{
  "username": "abc",
  "password": "abc123"
}, {
  "username": "richa",
  "password": "richa123"
}]

var result = loginDataList.map(function(data) {
  if (data.username && data.username.trim() != "" && data.password && data.password.trim() != "") {
    return "Present"
  } else {
    return "Not"
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that we must find not keys username and password but certain values, so we need traverse our array of objects:

```js
var loginDataList = [
    {'username': 'abc', 'password': 'abc123'},
    {'username': 'abcd', 'password': 'abc1234'},
    {'username': 'richa', 'password': 'richa123'}
];
var username = 'abcd';
var password = 'abc1234';
var userAndPasswordPresent = false;
for (var i in loginDataList) {
    if (loginDataList[i].username === username && loginDataList[i].password === password) {
        userAndPasswordPresent = true;
    }
}
console.log(userAndPasswordPresent);
```

Comment: @charlietfl, i had no idea about json,i tried indexof also,but even that wasn't working.

Comment: @Richa in your example not JSON present but array of objects. Probably you have JSON and you need convert it into array of objects, for such purposes you need this: `var loginDataList = JSON.parse(JsonString);`.

Comment: I don't wanna parse the json data.Can i not avoid for loop and instead go for $.each.But i am stuck with it .if(username1!='' && password1!='')
        {
          $.each(loginDataList , function (i, username1,password1)
           {

              if(username === loginDataList[i].username  && password ===loginDataList[i].password )
              {
                   $('h2').text('Logged In').delay(1000).hide(1);

          }


        });
}

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments below you want to check whether the username and password match with any one object in the JSON.

Here is the code for that.

```js
function checkUser(uname, pswd){ 
  var loginDataList = [
    {
      "username": "abc",
      "password": "abc123"
    },
    {
      "username": "richa",
      "password": "richa123"
    }
  ];

  var user = loginDataList.find(function(user){
    return user.username === uname && user.password === pswd 
  });
  if(user == null)
  {
    alert("nope");
  }
  else 
  {
    alert("woola");
  }
}

checkUser("abc","abc123");
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: No, i wanted to check whether user's input(username,password) exists in my Json entry or not.

Comment: Do you mean user.username and user.password value is set or not?

Comment: Or do you mean username and password keys exists in user json object?

Comment: in `{ "username" : "abc" }` `username` is *key* and `"abc"` is *value*

Comment: If u enter uname:mno,pswd:pqr. it should give nope coz these entries are not available in my json data(loginDataList). (abc,richa123) should also alert Nope coz these two are not mapped onto each other although available in the json data,(abc,abc123) or (richa,richa123) should alert Woola coz they are present in json data and also mapped onto each other.Hope this clears your confusion.